# Showing data in form view (instead of grid view) using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can anyone suggest how to bind data with the help of query in a Form view of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

I have done it in Grid view but as the requirement of a client is that I have to bind it to a Form view.